# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.d

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2012

I am working with visual studio 2012 C# windows form application. I am simply setting up my flow of forms by button_click events i.e form1 has a button Click Next which will close current form and open a new form Form2. Form2 has a "Click Next" Button which takes to Form3 and so on. In my forms, I am using form1.show() and form1.close() at required places. Please, look into this and replies are welcome.I am facing an Exception as **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.**
    MY program.cs is here

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Validate_Form());



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's definitely not all of your code.  Post the code where the exception originates.

Comment: Seems like you're building some kind of wizard.  Search on that...daisy-chaining forms is a clunky way to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 1):

In a Winform application, the window you specify in the `Main` method is your application's Main Form which gets associated with your Application's Process Handler in the OS (Windows). Processes can be categorized in 2 types. Windowed processes and Windowless ones. In a Windowed process, all the other forms in your application which are mapped to a Windows Window object will be a direct or indirect child of the main form of the application.
If you are designing a wizard as it looks it is what your are doing, my suggestion is to have your main form as a container and have the steps of the wizard as children gets loaded into your main form. For instance, you have a 2 step wizard: in this scenario, you will be needing 3 forms; the main form and the 2 steps. Main form will have the title and on the bottom area the navigation/control buttons (next/finish/cancel) and in the middle part of the form insert a container which loads the 2 steps. you need to set the properties of the steps as Window = none and ChildWindow = true. Now, when you load the main form, it loads the step 1 into its container area by setting the right child/parent relation in the main form's container object. Once user clicks on next, then you load the second form, hide the first one, and activate the second one. I think you got the idea. And this is how an actual wizard is designed. Let me know if you had any other questions/concerns.